# silently skip add with before_add association callback instead of raising an exception?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, callback

I'm trying to do this

```
 has_many :roles, :before_add => :enforce_unique

 def enforce_unique(assoc)
   false if exists? assoc
 end
```

From the docs: "If a before_add callback throws an exception, the object does not get added to the collection". The using false above does not prevent the add, so I'm forced to do this:

```
 def enforce_unique(assoc)
   raise if exists? assoc
 end
```

This way, it's true that it doesn't get added, but it also raises an exception that has to be handled. Not very useful to me here. I would prefer this to behave more like regular AR callback before_save, where returning FALSE also prevents the save (or add) but doesn't raise an exception.

In this case above, I would prefer this to just not add the assoc silently. Is there a way to do this? I missing something? Or is raising an exception the only option here?

Answer (score 2):

The way to solve it I think is to use `throw` and `catch`, which in Ruby are meant for flow control. Raising an exception is not a good fit, since this isn't an exceptional circumstance.

I ended up doing:

```
catch(:duplicate) do
  association.create({})
end
```

And then in the `before_add` callback, I did:

```
if(Class.where({}).first)
  throw :duplicate
end
```

More on throw/catch here:

http://rubylearning.com/blog/2011/07/12/throw-catch-raise-rescue-im-so-confused/

Answer (score 1):

If the association isn't polymorphic you can do something like:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :name_of_model
```

inside of Role where name_of_model us what you are associating with

Answer (score 1):

this question is a bit old, but i came across the same problem recently. here is how i solved it:

```
def enforce_unique |obj, x|
  v = obj.roles
  if i = v.index(x)
    v.slice! i
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this question is about saving rather than preventing it being included in the list temporarily (eg by a controller that is not interested in controlling its models) you could try overriding save in the related model and just not save it if the role exists:

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :roles

  def save
    super unless self.new_record? && user.has_existing_role?(self)
  end
end
```

Sidenote: I don't buy the skinny controller argument when used with the Active Record pattern as business logic has to be put somewhere. With a business domain poor pattern like Active Record (not referring to the Ruby AR gem specifically) it really needs to exist a layer above (ie in the controller layer), you may use service objects or the decorator pattern as a means to achieve this.

Another approach would be to override update methods like `<<` for the association and silently drop the role if it matches an existing one. Details on overriding association methods are in the [ActiveRecord Association Class Methods Documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html)